# Docusign Connect: Send status notification when unable to deliver to Recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I'm successfully working with Docusign Connect, but I would really like to see a status notification when Docusign is unable to deliver an email to one of the recipients specified in an envelope. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In your Connect Configuration settings (in the DocuSign web console), check the **Recipient Delivery Failed** checkbox within the "recipient events" section:

[image: Connect Settings]

With this setting selected, a Connect message will be generated if/when DocuSign receives a "bounce-back" for an email it sends to a recipient. The recipient status in the Connect message will be "**AutoResponded**" and the **AutoRespondedReason** element will include information about the SMTP error that resulted in the bounce-back.  For example:

```
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <Email>ztest12344587@gmail.com</Email>
                <UserName>zBob Jones</UserName>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Sent>2013-11-12T15:17:18.39</Sent>
                <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" />
                <AutoRespondedReason>smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 jz3si1128044obb.16 - gsmtp</AutoRespondedReason>
                <Status>AutoResponded</Status>
                <RecipientIPAddress />
                <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
                <RecipientId>18e43ddd-d88a-45c8-8d50-5018850ea31a</RecipientId>
            </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
        ...
    </EnvelopeStatus>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

Note: The "Recipient Delivery Failed" event (and subsequent Connect message with Status = "AutoResponded") is only used if “Send-Email-On-behalf-of” setting is disabled for the DocuSign account.  (Disabled is the default value for this setting, so you should be okay here -- if you want to verify or change that setting, someone with DocuSign will have to do it for you...it's not settable by you via the DocuSign web console admin interface.)

Comment: Thanks for your response Kim. I should have mentioned that all of the "recipient events" check boxes are selected on the DocuSign Connect configuration page. It looks like I'm only receiving "envelope events" and no "recipient events".

Comment: Hmmmm...that doesn't sound like the expected behavior. I'm not sure what to tell you then, other than perhaps dig a little deeper by enabling the Log ("Enable Log" checkbox in Connect configuration settings), sending/signing a new envelope after Log has been enabled, and then examining the Logs (Preferences >> Connect >> Logs). If Recipient events are selected and the Connect configuration is enabled ("Allow Envelope Publish" checked), you should see Connect messages in the Log for Recipient events.

Comment: After further analysis, it does look like I'm receiving recipient events, but not the "recipient delivery failed" event. I'll check with DocuSign about the internal "Send-Email-On-behalf-of" setting.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "AutoResponded" status (i.e., recipient delivery failed event) will only be triggered in cases where the sending DocuSign email server receives an SMTP error in response to sending an email.  This means you can only expect to see that status/event in cases like the receiving email server is unreachable, or the email address does not exist, etc. -- because these types of failure will trigger an SMTP error.  I don't believe that an out-of-office auto-reply will trigger the "AutoResponded" status ("recipient delivery failed" event).

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign Connect will not send a Recipient Delivery Failed for recipient email addresses such as **test@example.com**. However, it does send an email to the account owner with a subject of **DocuSign Email Delivery Status Notification (Failure)** and a body containing:

```
X-Postfix; delivery temporarily suspended: connect to
example.org[93.184.216.119]:25: Connection timed out
```

So, the account owner will get an email, but DocuSign Connect will not send a status update.

Using a sufficiently **undeliverable** address such as never@gonnawork.us results in a DocusignConnect status update.